# valueOf inside Mockito.when

Tags: eclipse, mockito, autoboxing

I have this construction:

```
Mockito.when(Integer.valueOf(serviceMock.getScore(bet))).thenThrow(e);
```

---

```
int getScore(final MatchBetModel bet);
```

what does it mean valueOf inside when?

I have strange eclipse specific, and if I delete valuOf I get error.

I cannot find place where I can fix it.

I hope your help!

Comment: What error are you getting? `Mockito.when(serviceMock.getScore(bet)).thenThrow(e);` is correct, you don't need `Integer.valueOf()`

Comment: boxing unboxing problem

Comment: post exact error. this must be something very specific to Eclipse. works fine in IntelliJ

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: it is specific eclipse configuration

Comment: What is the error you are getting?